# RPG inventory: Adding and Deleting Items

Tags: c#, game-engine

So far I have this:

```
class Inventory {
     private Potion[] potions;
     private Weapon[] weapons;
     private Armor[]  armor;
     private Food[]   food;
     private Ore[] ores;

     public int InventorySlots {get;set;}
     public Inventory() {
            InventorySlots = 10;
            BuildInventory();
     }
     public Inventory(int slots) {
            InventorySlots = slots;
            BuildInventory();
     }
     public void BuildInventory() {
            potions = new Potion[InventorySlots];
            weapons = new Weapons[InventorySlots];
            armor = new Armor[InventorySlots];
            food = new Food[InventorySlots];
            ores = new Ore[InventorySlots]
     }
}
```

Itf, for example, I wanted to add a new weapon to a 10 slot inventory, how would I add it and delete it?

Comment: Personally, I'd use lists instead of arrays - `private List<Weapon> weapons;`, then you can just add with `weapons.add(weaponInfo)`

Comment: It is not unreasonable to use an array if the number of items is fixed.

Comment: @EricJ. It depends on how much work you want to do managing the items in the array, and whether it's worth it.  The `List` class methods simplify a lot of the array processing, and give handy mnemonic names to the operations.

Comment: @user2097371 Are you certain that you want 10 slots for each item?  This doesn't appear to match up with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016647/inventory-system-in-c-sharp).

Comment: When I said 10 slot inventory I meant there 10 item slots, where the weapon would take up one.

Comment: If this is meant to contain a single inventory for all items then you are going about this is an odd way. Shoot me if I am wrong but wouldn't you want to make an "Item" class and store its type instead?

Comment: What you have is an Inventory object that - be default - can hold 50 item, with up to 10 of each type.  @Aleks is right... you need an `Item` type.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify matters significantly you could create a base class 'Item' that all of your item types are descended from:

```
public class Item
{
    // put any common attributes here
}

public class Armor : Item
{
    // define properties for Armor here
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    // define properties for weapons here
}
```

When you create child classes like this you can use an `Item` variable to store any of the derived classes.  You can create a new `Weapon` instance and assign it to an inventory slot of type `Item` for instance.  So your `Inventory` class becomes a collection of `Item`s.

Assuming you want a 1-to-1 mapping of array to inventory position, and prefer not to have things rearrange themselves, the array method is probably the way to go.

```
class Inventory
{
    // Array to store items
    public Item[] Items { get; private set; }

    // Inventory capacity is array length
    public int Capacity { get { return (Items == null) ? 0 : Items.Length; } }

    // Constructor
    public Inventory(int capacity = 10)
    {
        SetInventorySize(capacity);
    }

    // Set size of inventory, retaining contents where possible
    public void SetInventorySize(int cap)
    {
        if (cap <= 0)
            Items = null;
        else if (Items == null)
            Items = new int[cap];
        else
            Array.Resize(ref Items, cap);
    }

    // Get index number of first free slot in inventory
    public int FirstAvail()
    {
        if (Items != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (Items[i] == null)
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Add item to array, returning index or -1 on failure
    public int AddItem(Item item)
    {
        if (Items != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (Items[i] == null)
                {
                    Items[i] = item;
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The `Items` property is an array that you can store any `Item`-derived object, like `Armor` or `Weapon` above.  To add items to the list, find a clear spot (using the `FirstAvail` method for instance) and put the item into the Items list at that point.

When you are using items in the Inventory you need to determine what they are to figure out what to do with them.  You can use the `as` operation this way:

```
// get the first item in the inventory
Item item = inventory.Items[0];

if ((Armor armorItem = item as Armor) != null)
{
    // Code to execute for Armor items
    armorItem.Wear();
}
else if ((Weapon weaponItem = item as Weapon) != null)
{
    // Code to execute for Weapon items
    weaponItem.Equip();    
}
else if ((Potion potionItem = item as Potion) != null)
{
    // Code to execute for Potion items
    potionItem.Drink();
}
```

The `as` operation will check the true type of the object and return null if it doesn't match.  So if you store a `Potion` item in slot 0 of the inventory, it will not try to use it as an `Armor` or `Weapon` item.

Of course this is a contrived example.  It would be far more useful to define basic common actions in the `Item` class and override them in child classes.  Then you just call (for instance) `item.DefaultAction()` and have the implementation of `DefaultAction` overridden for each child type to perform the appropriate actions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you won't be able to set your weapons outside of the Inventory class since it's private, but if you were doing it inside of the Inventory class since it's an array you just assign the weapon to an index of the weapons array.  To remove it, you just set that index of weapons to null.

```
weapons[index] = weapon;  // add
weapons[index] = null;  // remove
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just make these public

```
private Potion[] potions;
private Weapon[] weapons;
private Armor[]  armor;
private Food[]   food;
private Ore[] ores;
```

But if you want to keep them private then make methods to access different positions of different arrays.

Example.

```
public Weapon getWeaponAtPositon(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < InventorySlots)
        return weapons[index];
    else
        return null;
}

public void setWeaponAtPositon(Weapon weapon, int index)
{
    if (weapon != null && index >= 0 && index < InventorySlots)
        weapons[index] = weapon;
}

public void deleteWeaponAtPositon(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < InventorySlots)
        weapons[index] = null;
}
```

You can repeat those for the different arrays that you have, this way you can only get access to one field at a time which gives you more secure way of modifying the array from outside the class (less chance of messing it up even though it is still pretty easy)

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure and check for *null* before using the object in an array position:

```
if (potions[4] != null)
{
    potions[4].DrinkMe();
}
```

You can remove an item by re-assigning *null*

```
potions[4] = null;
```

Note that all array positions will start out as *null*.  The code:

```
potions = new Potion[InventorySlots];
```

allocates an *array* of `Potion` but does not put a new `Potion` instance in each array slot.  It is up to you to do that.